# Get hyperlink url onclick

Tags: php, html

as the above stated, I wish to make once user click the hyperlink and it should copy into a variable in PHP.  Is it possible to do it?

This is what I have tried but nothing seems to come out?

**Code:**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function getdl(){
        var dlink = (document.getElementById('getdllink').getAttribute('onclick'))
         <? $url ?> = var dlink
    }
    </script>

<a id="getdllink" onclick="getdl()" href="#"><strong>Master Prospectus</strong></a></font>
            <? echo $url; ?>
```

I did something wrong? Please help. Thanks!

Comment: You may want to drop the <font>...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible what you are doing ... But it can be done by ajax.

What php does is:

[image]

So you need to make an ajax call and assign it to the php variable.

I would suggest you use jquery. It's very simple and effective.

You can send the data by

jquery:

```
$("id or class of link").live("click",function(){
var val = $("#getdllink").val();

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "some.php",
  data: { value :  val    }
}).done(function( msg ) {
  alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
});
 return false; // Prevent browser from visiting link
})
```

and in some.php

```
$var = $_POST['value'];
```

**the above method won't need to refresh the page**

to send this by url check the @PLB answer, it's good

Comment: I tried yours, it directly go to the link instead of getting the value of the variable.

Comment: @user1631889 but you can do this by  `return false i have edited in the answer

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you did it wrong. PHP is server-side so, it's executed before the client-side. This means that you can't directly assign javascript variable to php variable because it has already been interpreted. You have to send it using ajax.

Here's sample:

```
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
var myVar = 'myValue';
http.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if (http.readyState==4 && http.status==200){
        //Do whatever you want with respnse you'll get in http.responseText
        //http.responseText will contain text what php will print. In this
        //example value of myVar.
    }
}
http.open("GET","yourScript.php?myvar=" + myVar);
http.send();
```

On PHP side you can do:

```
echo $_GET['myvar'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to do it without AJAX or PHP...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getdl(){
    var dlink = (document.getElementById('getdllink').getAttribute('href'))
    document.getElementById('dest').innerHTML = dlink
    return false
}
</script>


<a id="getdllink" onclick="return (getdl())" href="http://www.google.com"><strong>Master Prospectus</strong></a><br />


<span id="dest"></span>
```

Comment: He wants to copy it in a php variable. There is more of a chance that this variable has more functions excluding an echo.

Comment: This was just for reference incase he wasn't sure what he wanted. If he wants to get the variable into the PHP then this is useless I know.